# How to hide coded messages in kaleidoscopes

Tags: pattern, visual, puzzle-creation

Has anyone ever made or ever heard of making coded messages using repeating patterns or colors in kaleidoscopes? I had the idea for a project and was wondering if anyone had any experience with something like this.

Comment: Could you describe your idea in a *little* more detail?

Comment: I thought about it some more. I think I would use a combination of shapes (square, triangle, circle, star) and alternating colors to stand for each letter. Possibly make a different color/pattern for double letters as well. So in the end, for example, an "A" would be 4 squares around the circle in yellow, "B" would be 6 squares around the circle in green, etc.

Comment: Are you talking about presenting kaleidoscope "images" or building a physical kaleidoscope? I think the latter would be impossible given that they generally rely on randomised movement of individual parts/shapes, which doesn't lend itself to encoding a fixed message. If the former, then like you hint at in your comment, you can just pick a "meaning" for a given pattern/shape/colour and build any message you want... Also, as a side note, the images a kaleidoscope produces are highly symmetric, so you're *really* just encoding your message into a single portion of the image.

Comment: No way could I make an actual kaleidoscope. Like you said, the random nature would be too hard to work with. I was thinking paper. I do a lot of papercraft. It would also be really cool to have a computer program that would generate the kaleidoscopes, so they could be animated, but I have no programming experience at all.